# MySQL weird rounding off results

Tags: mysql

I spotted some rounding bug in MySQL. Here is my query:

```
SELECT /*debugz*/ ROUND((SUM(grade)/2),0) AS grade, SUM(grade) FROM entry.computed_grade a WHERE a.stud_id='7901159' AND a.sy='2014' AND a.term=01 AND a.terms=01 AND a.catalog_no='Christian Life Formation';
```

and the result is this:

```
grade  sum(grade)  
------  ------------
    92           185
```

The grade result should be 93, not 92 because 185/2 = 92.5

Comment: Now I know why. I have to cast the grade as decimal to yield the correct answer. Data type issue.

Comment: As you said, a data type issue. Your grade is probably a floating point. SELECT ROUND(185/2, 0) gives 93 whereas SELECT ROUND(1.85E2, 0) gives 92. Suggest you cast the grade to an appropriate data type.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ceil` instead of `round`.

e.g `ceil(1.45) = 2`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

SELECT **CEIL**((SUM(grade)/2),0) AS grade, SUM(grade) FROM entry.computed_grade a WHERE ((a.stud_id='7901159') AND (a.sy='2014') AND (a.term=01) AND (a.terms=01) AND (a.catalog_no='Christian Life Formation'));

Answer (score 0):

You should check [rounding behavior artickle](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-rounding.html) for mysql. I believe here is the reason of your problem:

> For approximate-value numbers, the result depends on the C library. On
>   many systems, this means that ROUND() uses the “round to nearest even”
>   rule: A value with any fractional part is rounded to the nearest even
>   integer.

By the way it's [IEEE standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) for float point rounding, so you might want stay with it

Answer (score 0):

Do not "patch" this problem by tweaking the query.  Actually fix your database.  If you are not storing the "grade" column as the `DECIMAL` data type, and are instead using `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`, your design is inherently broken.

> Because floating-point values are approximate and not stored as exact values, attempts to treat them as exact in comparisons may lead to problems.
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/floating-point-types.html

This is not a bug in MySQL.  It is an inherent limitation in industry-standard floating point number storage.  Use `DECIMAL` columns to store meaningful, precise numbers, and the other two types only when low storage space or a wide range of allowable values are more important than precision.